# is an SSIS package a WF based workflow

Tags: ssis, workflow

I am new to the Microsoft Technology Stack. I happened to take a superficial look at both Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) and the SSIS packages that can be used to create ETL programs. Both looked strikingly similar. Can anybody tell me whether SSIS is built over WF or is it related to WF in any other way? Or is it just that the similarity ends with the way they look and are completely different technologies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are different technologies.
SSIS has been around since SQL Server 2005 came out.
WF was introduced first with .NET Framework 3.5 and then carried forward with .NET 4.0.
Both have a graphical  flow driven visual interface but they really do not have much in common to the best of my knowledge.